# Loading parent class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Got some error in codeigniter when trying to call parent class. This is what I did :

```
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
   function __construct()
   {
       parent::Controller();
   }
}
```

And this is the error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-nettuts-d3\application\controllers\email.php on line 11

Comment: Why is it CI_Controller instead of just Controller? Which version is this? I reckon it should be  class Email extends Controller { ... but maybe it depends on release version...

Comment: The latest version is CI_Controller. You can refer here - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: Well it seems like you need to use  parent::__construct(); syntax as the answer suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of CI are you using? Tried `parent::__construct();` instead of `parent::Controller();`?

Comment: I watch this tutorial - http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-3/

He use parent::Controller(); and he's code works! That's what me litte bit confuse

Comment: @Zhaf Probably they were using a code-igniter version that was compatible with php4. Latest codeigniter needs php 5.1.2. Here is some code on their documentation that suggests parent::__construct(), http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#reserved